# MacBook Pro Boot and Power Issue

Tags: macos, boot, mac, battery, power

I have a MacBook Pro which is having some trouble.

Firstly, when the laptop is not plugged in, it will not turn on. When the laptop is plugged in, the battery indicator is green, fully charged, and will turn on.

When booting, the screen is all white for a minute, then flashes a folder with a question mark.

The only boot option that kind of works is holding the options key. However, the screen still stays white, but the mouse cursor begins to show and the folder with a question mark doesn't show.

I am at a loss here. This laptop is no longer under warranty and it is about 6 years old. The laptop has been taken great care of. Seems to have occurred out of spontaneously.

I haven't yet tried using the OS X Installation disk, nor any type of recovery disk. I am investigating that now and do not have one readily available.

Any suggestions?

- Not boot without power cord.
- Boot with power cord and shows battery fully charged
- Boot screen flashes folder with question mark
- No boot options work

Comment: The battery is dead. The OS may or may not be corrupt.

Comment: Thank you. I'll replace that, seems like the best start at the least.

Comment: Hold down Cmd-D at boot for hardware diags mode. Run the short test, and if it doesn’t find anything, do the long test.

Comment: I had this same problem. Except my diagnostic was easy. I spilled water on it. I replaced a logic board on the inside, $700 later it was back to normal.

Comment: @Spiff - No options that work at boot, including CMD-D.

Comment: @DrZoo - I hope it doesn't come to that. The laptop was just sitting on a shelf for almost 2 years without use. Last time it was used was to update it, then it just stayed on a shelf.

Comment: Actually, the reset PRAM option does work, but doesn't resolve anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit dated; was searching through old stuff.

To solve this issue I first replaced the battery. Once the battery was replaced the hard-drive wiring hardness had become fried. I went online and ordered a wiring harness. Easy to replace. Good as new.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. Macbook pro 13" (2017) booting worked fine when plugged in, while when in battery mode regularly failed to boot showing folder question mark icon.

First did a clean install, but the problem remained. In the end what solved it for me was disconnecting the battery for a short while and then reconnecting it.